# Drivers not updating on "display" field

Tags: python, animation, particles, drivers

I have an issue where my driver value never updates. I want to drive the "display" % field under particles, but the driver value never changes.
These pictures should explain better:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what's wrong here?
Or is there another way to globally change the display % of particles?
I'm using 2.77.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what your issue is here.  Particle draw_percentage is an integer with values ranging from 0 to 100.  In both your example images you are looking at a transform channel, eg x location, which has a negative float value eg -70.91, which will map to 0 as a value for draw_percentage.

Comment: Hi, yes, the strange thing is that the driver value changes when its mapped to the rotation, but not when mapped to draw percentage. the bit i underlined never changes, no matter where you move the empty, while using the same empty and the value does change on the second one.

Comment: I'm confused, the first image has the Cube as the driver variable target object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i found the issue.
***The Display field only updates when you change frame***, it will not update if you move the empty but stay on the same frame, if you move one forward or back it works.

You can also use python to control this field. ( Firstsplash is name of particle settings, replace with whatever the name of you particle settings is )

```
import bpy

bpy.data.particles["Firstsplash"].draw_percentage = 1
bpy.data.particles["Firstsplash.001"].draw_percentage = 1
bpy.data.particles["Firstsplash.003"].draw_percentage = 1
```

Comment: How are you moving the empty?  I find the driver variable value, and the driven prop, in this case ps.draw_percentage change after a translation in the UI without a frame change, making the statement "The Display field only updates when you change frame" rather misleading, or most likely wrong.